# Certificate handshaking is successful sometimes and sometimes it fails to handshake successfully. This is very inconsistent

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am seeing a very weird issue. From my spring boot application, I call an external service over https by exporting the .cer file from the browser and loading it programmatically. I have called the external certificate immediately after springboot loads. Once I start the application, I get the following error 50% of the time and the remaining 50% of the time the application starts correctly.

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am using URLConnection to call the external service. creating SSLContext and adding it to the URLConnection using conn.setSSLSocketFactory()

```
 private static SSLContext loadTrustedStore(String certPath)
    throws ShoppingException {
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("certificates/"+certPath);
        InputStream inputStreams = resource.getInputStream();
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inputStreams);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null,null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);
        tmf.init(ks);
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        inputStreams.close();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ShoppingException(ex);
    }
    return sslContext;
}
```

Then finally hitting the service with the following piece of code

```
outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(requestBodyMsg.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
```

The success rate of the **same** service call is 50%. Once it fails and if I restart the server again and it is successful.

The same code works when I hit the same service in the lower environment 100% of the time. I have compared the cipher in the network connection between the lower and higher environment of the target service. They are the same.

The TLS information on the postman console log is

authorizationError: "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"
authorized: false
cipher: {…}
name: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
version: "TLSv1/SSLv3"

Any help would be appreciated.

Another interesting observation is: if I start the application in debug mode and keep pressing F6 to move the execution then the handshaking is successful 100% of the time.

Comment: Get a SSL debug logs for the working scenario and non- working scenario and check where it fails.   Please refer this[1,2] to get the SSL debug logs.     [1]https://gist.github.com/62mkv/5811f70933692b0d51c79b3f40540cec.     [2]https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783

Comment: A similar problem is discussed here[1]                                                   [1]https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/

Comment: Whenever I see "works 50% of the time" I consider the possibility of unsafe concurrency. However, all the objects in `loadTrustedStore()` appear to be local, except perhaps the certificate file. Is there any chance that file is being created or changed during the running of the application?

Comment: As suggested by @Senthuran, I enabled the SSL debug. When it failed, I see the below error. On the other hand when it runs successfully, it says "found trusted certificate"

***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: The certificate does not change nither on the external application nor on my application.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but we have a self-signed cert in cacerts. I am unable to pin point out when the issue comes, but sometimes I get this error you write, sometimes it is a success. I also saw that this didn't depend on a restart, but like after a day of otherwise inactive server state (nobody called that test instance) it either breaks or starts to work again. I am already mixing up what I did with the docker container and what not. But weird, the certificate is in the trust store, but this message indicates that it doesn't.

Comment: First my idea was that this error message was because of a strict hostname verification (but why it works sometimes, when the cert is the same). If I create a test tool in python to make a connection to that server (this is a special protocol though), it gets me exactly a hostname verif. issue, but if I omit that, it is ok. Becausee this is randomly working sometimes, even if the reason is hostname verification, I can't verify a workaround for that (creating a custom dummy hostname verifier), becase then I don't know if it works of the change or it is in the "winning phase" at that time.